# Icons after link: Break with last word

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, word-break

How can I make icons after a link stick to the last word:

```css
div {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <span><a href="#">Many words here in this text breakWithTheIcons</a>&#xfeff;<i class="fa fa-heart"></i><i class="fa fa-music"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Test: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJGMBr

Comment: By applying display:inline to icons(<i></i>)

Comment: Do you have to use fixed width on div?

Comment: @Nenad Vracar: In this case, yes. `display:inline` fixes it as Dhaval posted.

Comment: Ok if not you could do this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obGqpv